# Angular Bootstrap modal is loading whole page into the modal (13.0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm following the documentation for [Bootstrap AngularJS 13.0](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.0/#/modal)

I not allowed to update bootstrap (for various reasons).

I've copied the documentation almost exactly but I'm getting the following effect (the whole site is being loaded into the modal, ignore black boxes):

[image: Boot strap problem, ignore black boxes.]

My code is as follows:

***navbar.html***

```
<!-- Options drop down for not logged in. -->
        <div ng-hide="UserInfoService.isLoggedIn()" class="navbar-options pull-right" dropdown keyboard-nav dropdown-toggle>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav">
                <li role="menuitem"><a ng-click="openRegisterModal();">{{'Register' | translate}}</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">{{'Login' | translate}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

***Navbar controller, this includes the injected*** `$modal`

```
$scope.openRegisterModal = function() {
        $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'register-modal.html',
            controller: 'RegisterModalController',
            size: 'sm'
        });
    };
```

***Register modal template, in it's own file***

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterModalController">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="register-modal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Test body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        Test footer
    </div>
</script>
</div>
```

Register modal controller, the console log is called once on open.

```
'use strict';

//Instance of register modal.
angular.module('passionForgeApp').controller('RegisterModalController', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {

    console.log('Did load RegisterModalController');

}]);
```

I cannot figure out why the modal is loading the whole site in it :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because if you want to load the modal you need to also include the template on the same html.. Kinda silly would have though that was automatic.

Anyhow code to resolve this was:

```
<div ng-include="'app/components/some-modal/some-modal.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `templateUrl` was probably incorrect. This could have done it:

`templateUrl: 'app/components/some-modal/some-modal.html'`